# Cannot start brunch server

Tags: ember.js, brunch, emblem.js

I first start a new project

```
brunch new https://github.com/wordofchristian/brunch-with-hampsters
```

I then try to start a watch and server

```
$brunch w -s
```

I get this error

```
node_modules/emblem-brunch/lib/index.js:27
        this.window.run(fs.readFileSync(paths.jquery, 'utf8'));

TypeError: Object object has no method 'run'
at EmblemCompiler.module.exports.EmblemCompiler.setup (node_modules/emblem-brunch/lib/index.js:27:21)
at new EmblemCompiler (node_modules/emblem-brunch/lib/index.js:43:14)
```

I have no idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with my senior programmer.

It turns out I didn't have build-essential package install on my ubuntu. It was looking for g++ command.

Likewise when I do a npm install, it needs sudo. After the g++ fix and the sudo npm install, I was able to launch

```
brunch w -s
```